# Match package name(s) using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have Python import statements that I want to match using regex.

I have these four types of strings,

1. import collections as c

I want to match just the last word 'c'. => import collections as **c**

2. from datetime import date as dt

I want to match just the last word 'dt'. => from datetime import date as **dt**

3. from sys import stdout, stderr, stdin

I want to match everything after import. => from sys import **stdout**, **stderr**, **stdin**

4. import re

I want to match just the last word 're' => import **re**

Currently I am using inbuit way to split by "import" and get the string after that which seems inefficient.

I tried doing this,

```
(?<=import ).*
```

but it just matches case 3 and case 4, it doesn't match case 1 and case 2.

How do I do this using regex?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, you are expected to show your attempt first, please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay so your question is, given a .py file, find all the files that were imported, and in case, they were imported with an alias you want to find the alias write?

Comment: The following statements are strings. So give any strings of three of these kinds, I want to extract alias or the package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your four cases, and I believe it should be mostly general:

```
re.search('import( \S* as)? (.*)$',your_string)[2]
```

briefly, you search for all the words that come at the end (which is basically what you always want) after `'import'`, but you want `XXX as` to be excluded in case these follow the word `import` so you put that as an optional match (in parentheses). Finally, you select your second matching item. Hope this is clear